# Restricting output to only allow localhost using iptables

Tags: firewall, iptables

I would like to restrict outbound traffic to only localhost using iptables. I already have a default DROP policy on OUTPUT and a rule REJECTing all traffic. I need to add a rule above that in the OUTPUT chain.

I have seen a couple different examples for this type of rule, the most common being:

`-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT`

and

`-A OUTPUT -o lo -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT`

Is there any reason to use the latter rather than the former? Can packets on `lo` have an address other than 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your machine has multiple interfaces, and you try to communicate with the IP on one of these other interfaces, the traffic will actually go over the `lo` interface. Linux is smart enough to figure out this traffic is destined for itself, and not try to use the real interface.

The rule `-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT` will allow this other traffic, while the rule `-A OUTPUT -o lo -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT` would reject it.

.

You can see everything the kernel will route over the loopback interface by running

```
ip route show type local table all
```

(just note the first value, which is either an IP or a network/mask)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can have other addresses.  You can possibly see anything from `127.0.0.0/8` in-use.  On Debian/Ubuntu system addresses in the `127.0.0.0/8` range are used to deal with an Apache issue.

Other addresses can also be assigned, but this is very rare.

Answer (score 0):

> I already have a default DROP policy on OUTPUT and a rule REJECTing
>   all traffic

That makes no sense; they achieve the same end.
The default policy to DROP is sufficient.

The rule you're looking for is probably

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

But some more experience with iptables will (hopefully) teach you not to do that; use input rules instead.

Comment: In this case since I'd prefer for the blocked outbound traffic to be REJECTed and not DROPped and since REJECT is not a valid default policy I have that rule. In any case, that part isn't relevant to my question regarding localhost.